# Javascript: buffer.js:202 Rest call throw new TypeError(kFromErrorMsg)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to perform first Rest call using javascript. My code is below:

```
        var https = require('https');
        var user =  '<Domain>\\*****';
        var pass = '******';

        process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

        /**
         * HOW TO Make an HTTP Call - GET
         */
        // options for GET
        var optionsget = {
            host : '**************', // here only the domain name
            // (no http/https !)
            port : 443,
            path : '/rest/api/latest/plan/dummy1/branch', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
            method : 'GET', // do GET
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
            auth : { 
                username: user,
                password: pass
            }   
        };

        console.info('Options prepared:');
        console.info(optionsget);
        console.info('Do the GET call');

        // do the GET request
        var reqGet = https.request(optionsget, function(res) {
            console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
            // uncomment it for header details
          console.log("headers: ", res.headers);


            res.on('data', function(d) {
                console.info('GET result:\n');
                process.stdout.write(d);
                console.info('\n\nCall completed');
            });

        });

        reqGet.end();
        reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
```

However above is generating error as below. Please help to understand this issue and how to fix it?

---

Do the GET call
***buffer.js:202
  throw new TypeError(kFromErrorMsg);
  ^

TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.

```
at Function.Buffer.from (buffer.js:202:9)
at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:198:27)
at Object.request (http.js:38:10)
at Object.request (https.js:239:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\som_temp\test.js:49:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)***
```